# How can I install or upgrade to sqlite 3.33.0 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sqlite, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get

I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04 with SQLite3. SQLite 3 is at version 3.22.0 and I need to upgrade it to version 3.33.0 to take advantage of new functionality that is available. If I remove and reinstall SQLite3 with apt-get, it just re=installs 3.22.0. How can I upgrade to the latest version of SQLite3?

Comment: Just download and compile the source. It installs into /usr/local by default and tends to just work with anything using the sqlite dynamic library.

Comment: If you're still using 18.04 in 2023: https://askubuntu.com/a/1352404/20688

Answer (score 29):

I have tried to compile the latest sqlite3 from source and it does not work with the packages of Ubuntu 18.04.

Eventually, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 20.04(Focal Fossa), and it comes with Sqlite 3.31.

If you want the latest Sqlite 3.34(at the time of this post), you need to download and build it yourself.

The steps are pretty straight forward.

##### **Step 1 - Download the Source code**

```
wget https://sqlite.org/2021/sqlite-autoconf-3340100.tar.gz
```

##### **Step 2 - Extract the tarball**

```
tar -xvf sqlite-autoconf-3340100.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3340100
```

##### **Step 3 - Configure**

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
./configure
```

##### **Step 4 - Make**

```
make
```

##### **Step 4.5 - Get rid of the old version**

```
sudo apt-get purge sqlite3
```

##### **Step 5 - Make Install**

```
sudo make install
```

##### **Step 6 - Add to path**

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"  # also add in your .bashrc
```

##### **Step 7 - Verify the installation**

```
sqlite3 --version
3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07 10e20c0b43500cfb9bbc0eaa061c57514f715d87238f4d835880cd846b9ebd1f
```

Comment: I tried your steps above to the letter, but step 6 does not work: "-bash: /usr/bin/sqlite3: No such file or directory". Can I only reach sqlite3 in its own folder?

Comment: You are building on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Yes. Someone else with more Linux knowledge helped me, apparently the folder where sqlite3 gets installed is not part of the PATH, so it had to be added manually.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer so that if somebody faces a similar situation, they have that note for reference.

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa), it needs to instead be :

`export PATH="/usr/local/lib:$PATH"  # also add in your .bashrc`