# SQLite3 error when setting Output Format to "table" (.mode table)

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu, command-line-interface, wsl-2

I am using SQLite3 on WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). When I attempt to set the output format mode to table, I get the following error:

```
sqlite> .mode table
Error: mode should be one of: ascii column csv html insert line list quote tabs tcl
```

I've updated SQLite3 to the most current version, and I am still not seeing "Table" as an option.

According to the [SQLite3 documentation](https://sqlite.org/cli.html), I should be seeing 14 different modes to choose from.

Thank you!

Comment: What version does sqlite3 display when you start it?

Comment: 3.31.1 - When I update sqlite3 in WSL2 I get "sqlite3 is already the newest version (3.31.1-4ubuntu0.2)"

Comment: table output mode was added in 3.33.0.

Comment: The solution to your (and my) problem should lie [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861331/how-can-i-install-or-upgrade-to-sqlite-3-33-0-on-ubuntu-18-04).

Answer (score 0):

WSL2 does not have the latest version of sqlite3.

The solution is to upgrade using the instructions here:

> [How can I install or upgrade to sqlite 3.33.0 on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64861331/how-can-i-install-or-upgrade-to-sqlite-3-33-0-on-ubuntu-18-04)